# Paperclip is missing the Protocol (https) with Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In production.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    s3_host_name: "s3.#{ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}.amazonaws.com",
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
        access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
}
```

I don't have anything in the initializers/paperclip.rb.

In my model:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :photo, styles: {
      thumb: '100x100>',
      square: '200x200#',
      medium: '300x300>'
  }
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  def photo_url=(url)
    self.photo = URI.parse(url)
  end
end
```

And then I test it out:

```
m = Model.new
m.photo_url = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/sports-grill-miami.jpg"
m.save!
m.photo.url(:thumb)
"//s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/buckets/photos/000/000/005/thumb/sports-grill-miami.jpg?1495237443"
```

Why is the HTTPS protocol missing? This is crashing my android application because it requires a protocol to connect to URL. Do I need to hardcode the URL or can Paperclip handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly add the protocol to your configuration:

```
:s3_protocol => :https
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16179226)

Comment: this does provide an answer to the question, with or without expanding on it, i posted the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the scheme on `paperclip` configuration as below:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
      s3_host_name: "s3.#{ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}.amazonaws.com",
      storage: :s3,
      :s3_protocol => :https, # <- added this
      s3_credentials: {
          bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
          access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
          secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
          s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
      }
  }
```

`:s3_protocol => :https` will assign the scheme `https` to the url's generated for your amazon s3 assets. Refer to [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) for more details.