# Paperclip S3 url doesn't include http or https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Right now when I call the `url` method I'm getting this:

`//us-west-2.amazonaws.com/enviosya/0b4ee5fbb3ebd12b5f86a9f0f6c908a8ceb7e03a.jpg?1507422471`

No https or http on it.

This is my config:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
       storage: :s3,
       url: ':s3_domain_url',
       s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
       s3_credentials: {
           bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
           access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ID'],
           secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET'],
           s3_host_name: ENV['S3_ENDPOINT']
       }
   }
```

And here is the code in the model:

```
  has_attached_file :receiver_signature,
                    url: '/system/:hash.:extension',
                    hash_secret: ENV['PAPERCLIP_SECRET']
```

Is there something wrong with my config or with the url value in the model?

I have the same problem if I avoid hashing the url and add this to the config:

`path: :class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension'`.

In that case `url` returns:

`//us-west-2.amazonaws.com/enviosya/shipments/receiver_signatures/000/000/011/original/signature.jpg?1507423398`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080512/paperclip-is-missing-the-protocol-https-with-amazon-s3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paperclip is missing the Protocol (https) with Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080512/paperclip-is-missing-the-protocol-https-with-amazon-s3)