# Paperclip image_tag does not show image with S3 and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using Paperclip for S3 image uploading in my Rails (4.2) app. Everything works fine, except of the fact that the image_tag does not show the image but the title of the image. What am I missing?

**recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }


  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, attributes: :image, less_than: 1.megabytes

end
```

**Recipe show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @recipe.name %>
</p>

<div class="col-xs-12" style="height:400px">
  <%= image_tag @recipe.image.url(:original) %>
</div>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipe_path(@recipe) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', recipes_path %>
```

**UPDATE: Solution**

> Two things are needed to make it work:
>
> 1. Add `s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com"` to config. This is a workaround as suggested [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2151).
> 2. Add `:s3_protocol => :https` to config as aws-sdk-2 needs this explicitly (as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: everything looks fine can you check image exists on s3 URL by pasting URL in the browser

Comment: yes it is there. if i got to my bucket in my s3 console i find the image and can retrieve the url there. it is: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/powerrecipes/recipes/images/000/000/001/original/pexels-photo-461198.jpeg

Comment: try to put this url directly in the browser by inspecting image_tag. PermanentRedirect error in browser console?

Comment: I inspected the elements of the page in Chrome and it shows me the following URL for the image_tag: <img src="//s3.amazonaws.com/powerrecipes/recipes/images/000/000/003/medium/iStock-616862250.jpg?1514987743" alt="Istock 616862250">. If i try to open the URL in the browser it says PermanentRedirect error and "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

Comment: its because your image url is not taking https. can you check that the above code you posted is correct

Answer (score 0):

In aws-adk-2 you need to specify s3 protocol explicitly in your configuration :s3_protocol => :https.

latest versions of paperclip depend on aws-sdk-2. so you have to specify the protocol.

In this way this way this will save your image URL with https.

This answe will help you [see the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080512/paperclip-is-missing-the-protocol-https-with-amazon-s3). you have the same problem.

Comment: Ok I added it. Now the link has https but the error remains the same...

Comment: I updated my question. Obviously one more step is needed.

Comment: Glad it helped :)